# WooCommerce Review Stars in shortcode

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm a self taught front end web developer and need some help with some code.

I found a way to add random reviews via shortcode to the website I'm working on (credit: [WooCommerce: Display some reviews randomly on home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923643/woocommerce-display-some-reviews-randomly-on-home-page)). I've edited the function to suit my clients website.

However, I want to display the stars along with the title and the comment. I have no idea how to do this. Can anybody help?

```
add_shortcode('woo_reviews', 'get_random_woo_reviews');

function get_random_woo_reviews( $atts ){
// Shortcode Attributes
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'limit' => '3', // <== Set to 3 reviews by default
), $atts, 'woo_reviews' );

global $wpdb;

// The SQL random query on product reviews
$comments = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}comments c
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts p ON c.comment_post_ID = p.ID
    WHERE c.comment_type = 'review' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT %d
", intval( esc_attr($atts['limit']) ) ) );

ob_start(); // Start buffering

## CSS applied styles
?>
<style>
    ul.product-reviews, ul.product-reviews li { list-style: none; margin:0; padding:0px 24px 24px; line-height: normal;}
    ul.product-reviews li { display:block; max-width: 300px, padding: 10px; display:inline-block; vertical-align: text-top;}
    ul.product-reviews li .title {font-size: 16px; color: #F14500}
    ul.product-reviews li .content {max-width: 300px; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 6px;}
    ul.product-reviews li .author, ul.product-reviews li .date  {display: block; font-size: 16px; color: #F14500}
</style>
<?php

## HTML structure
?>
<ul class="product-reviews"><?php

foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
    ?>
    <li>
        <h4 class="author"><?php printf( __(" %s") . ' ', '<strong>' . $comment->comment_author . '</strong>' ); ?></h4>
        <div class="content"><?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?></div>

    </li>
    <?php
}
?></ul><?php

return ob_get_clean(); // Return the buffered output
}
```

Comment: Does this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227121/how-do-you-add-the-star-ratings-for-products-in-woocommerce help? (Note, ignore the answer that was accepted and look at the others - don't be tempted to do direct sql calls yourself).

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into the various solutions and see what works for my site. The back end code is such a learning curve!