# Display some WooCommerce product reviews with limited content length randomly

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, review, maxlength

I am making shortcode for reviews Based on [WooCommerce: Display some reviews randomly on home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923643/woocommerce-display-some-reviews-randomly-on-home-page/57924630#57924630) to put on other pages. How can i limit reviews by character numbers, like 100 or 200 characters. SO they will not be too long and fit any page.

I am using following code for reviews now

```
function get_random_five_stars_products_reviews( $atts ) {
    // Extract shortcode attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'limit' => 5, // number of reviews to be displayed by default
    ), $atts, 'woo_reviews' ) );

    $comments = get_comments( array(
        'status'      => 'approve',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type'   => 'product',
        'meta_query'  => array( array(
            'key'     => 'rating',
            'value'   => '5',
        ) ),
    ) );

    shuffle($comments);

    $comments = array_slice( $comments, 0, $limit );

    $html = '<ul class="products-reviews">';
    foreach( $comments as $comment ) {
        $rating = intval( get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) );
        $html .= '<li class="review">';
        $html .= '<div>'.get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ).'</div>';
        if ( $rating > 4 ) $html .= wc_get_rating_html( $rating );
        $html .= '<div>' .$comment->comment_content.'</div>';
        $html .= "<div>Posted By :".$comment->comment_author." On ".$comment->comment_date. "</div>";
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    return $html . '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode('woo_reviews', 'get_random_five_stars_products_reviews');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit displayed 5 starts reviews with a content that doesn't exceed a specific length *(here 100 characters)* use the following:

```
function get_random_five_stars_products_reviews( $atts ) {
    // Extract shortcode attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'limit'      => 5, // number of reviews to be displayed by default
        'length'     => 100, // Limit comments text content lenght
        'show_stars' => true, // Or "false" to hide
    ), $atts, 'woo_reviews' ) );

    $comments = get_comments( array(
        'status'      => 'approve',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type'   => 'product',
        'meta_query'  => array( array(
            'key'     => 'rating',
            'value'   => '5',
        ) ),
    ) );

    shuffle($comments);

    $count = 0; // Initializing
    $html  = '<ul class="products-reviews">';
    
    foreach( $comments as $comment ) {
        $content = $comment->comment_content;
        if( strlen($content) <= $length && $count < $limit ) {
            $rating = intval( get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) );
            $html .= '<li class="review">';
            $html .= '<div>'.get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ).'</div>';
            if ( $show_stars ) {
                $html .= wc_get_rating_html( $rating );
            }
            $html .= '<div>' .$content. '</div>';
            $html .= "<div>Posted By :".$comment->comment_author." On ".$comment->comment_date. "</div>";
            $html .= '</li>';
            $count++; // Increase count
        }

        if ( $count == $limit ) {
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $html . '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode('woo_reviews', 'get_random_five_stars_products_reviews');
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: 'length' => 100; // Limit comments text content lenght.
This line has error. Code doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I think i didn't express my thoughts correctly. How to choose from all reviews, only reviews that have in it 100 symbols or less. Now your code just cutting them, that can be easily done with css. I just want to display short reviews.

Comment: @Polmario Updated… Try it.